# remove all boxes with one element

Tags: j

How do I remove all boxes with one element? E.g. I would like to turn this:

```
┌─────┬───┬─┬─────┐
│1 1 1│2 2│3│2 2 2│
└─────┴───┴─┴─────┘
```

Into this:

```
┌─────┬───┬─────┐
│1 1 1│2 2│2 2 2│
└─────┴───┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose your value is in `a`:

```
   ]a =. 1 1 1; 2 2; 3; 2 2 2
┌─────┬───┬─┬─────┐
│1 1 1│2 2│3│2 2 2│
└─────┴───┴─┴─────┘
```

The trick here is to get the length of each box:

```
   #@> a
3 2 1 3
```

If the length > 1, you get a "mask" you can pass to [copy](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d400.htm).

```
   1 < #@> a
1 1 0 1

   a #~ 1 < #@> a
┌─────┬───┬─────┐
│1 1 1│2 2│2 2 2│
└─────┴───┴─────┘
```

[`13:`](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d310n.htm) will tell us how to make this tacit:

```
   13 : 'y #~ 1<#@>y'
] #~ 1 < #@>
```

As it happens, needing to put `id` in the last position of a fork is exactly what a hook does, so we can even simplify one more step:

```
   remsingles =. #~ 1 < #@>
   remsingles a
┌─────┬───┬─────┐
│1 1 1│2 2│2 2 2│
└─────┴───┴─────┘
```

Comment: Great answer. What do you mean by "13: will tell us how to make this tacit:"?

Comment: @Fuser97381 That's the [explicit](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d310n.htm) built-in, and calling it with 13 and a string of code will attempt to rewrite an explicit function (with variables `x` and `y`) into a tacit function without formal parameters. It's a very helpful tool for learning about tacits!

Comment: That's really interesting. I found this documentation for anyone else who ends up here wondering the same thing: http://jsoftware.com/help/jforc/explicit-to-tacit_converter.htm

Answer (score 4):

An alternative view of @Daniel's answer.

Filtering a list is very common and the usual idiom is:

```
(#~ filter)
```

where `filter` is a verb returning `1` for elements to be kept and `0` for those to be discarded. In this case your filter is

```
(1 < size) for_each_element
```

Translating `size` as `#` and `for_each_element` as verb `"every"` (`&>`), the filter is

```
(1 < #) &>
```

So,

```
remsingles =: #~ (1 < #) &>
remsingles a
┌─────┬───┬─────┐
│1 1 1│2 2│2 2 2│
└─────┴───┴─────┘
```